# Geckodriver session timeout in Karate

Tags: gitlab, cucumber, gitlab-ci, karate, geckodriver

I'm currently trying to launch Karate tests on a Gitlab runner.
I have a geckodriver launched with the services module Gitlab CI and a very strange call is being made in tests.

> org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: http call failed after 30021 milliseconds for url: http://geckodriver-host:4444/session/7219bd73-4bcf-4ebe-befb-32d124586d9e/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/execute/sync/screenshot

Anyone as an idea what is this url ?

Thanks

Comment: no idea ! I don't know if you can replicate this for others, if you can - please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I've seen a undefined URL on my code ... The base URL was good in local but not in the terraform environnement